# Скрипт PowerShell для запуска программ, требующих ввода логина и пароля в окне

Tags: авторизация, powershell

Есть программа, которая после запуска выдает окно, в которое надо ввести логин и пароль для дальнейшей работы. В целях автоматизации ввода логина и пароля написал программу на Сишарп. Пробую написать скрипт на PowerShell, и не получается. Окно с полями для ввода логина пароля нахожу и активирую. А как туда ввести данные? Есть ли в PowerShell аналоги операторов SendKeys.SendWait(User)?

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать класс [SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) из `System.Windows.Forms`:

```powershell
# Добавляем в PowerShell класс для использования функции SetForegroundWindow из user32.dll
Add-Type @"
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  public class SFW {
     [DllImport("user32.dll")]
     [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
     public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
  }
"@

# Загружаем в PowerShell сборку System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Строка, которую мы пошлем приложению
$Keys = 'This is SPARTA!{ENTER}All your base are belong to us!'

# Задержка между командами
$Wait = 3

# Запускаем процесс
$ps = Start-Process -FilePath 'notepad.exe' -PassThru

# Задержка, чтобы процесс успел загрузиться
Start-Sleep -Seconds $Wait

# Выводим окно процесса на передний план
[void][SFW]::SetForegroundWindow($ps.MainWindowHandle)

# Задержка, чтобы процесс успел переключить окно
Start-Sleep -Seconds $Wait

# Посылаем строку
[void][System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($Keys)
```